# Django: How to update related model fields when creating model

Tags: django, django-models

Django 1.11

I have multiple models that have the same fields as `status`, for example repairOrder, statusUpdate which have an odometer field just as status does. When a user makes a new statusupdate or repairOrder I would like it to update certain fields within the status model as well. The way I see it there are four options

1. overriding the save() method on statusupdate
2. [using signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save)
3. [custom model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods), which could query for related models and update fields
4. a method on the model that would call the related model
   and update where I wanted it to.

I've removed some fields to make the example more simple.

```
class Status(models.Model):
     odometer = models.IntegerField()
     vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     ...

class statusUpdate(models.Model):
     odometer = models.IntegerField()
     vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     ...
```

When a user creates a new stautsUpdate, I would like the odometer on Status to be set aswell.

**Q:** What would be the Django way of updating a related model's fields?

EDIT: Edited alot of the question to clarify the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually all the ways are good and have their own pros and cons.

If these models are in different apps and are mostly independent, signals is cool. The good thing about it is that it won't bother you in normal cases and you will have much more control.

Doing it through overriding save() method is good idea, but if you don't have to do it everytime or most of the times but at very specific times, create a different method through which you will call save() method along with doing whatever else you want. Good thing here is that you can put as many conditions, try catch exceptions and if else conditions and it wont affect the save method.

You must find what suits the need of the situation best. From my own experience and what people say, don't use signals until you have to.

Answer (score 0):

The odometer field in status update is not needed as you already have a foreign key to Status model so you have access to every field of Status model. Just remove the odometer from statusmodel and then when you a user do a statusupdate update the odometer field.

```
status_update_instance.odometer = some value
status_update.save()
```

The above is an instance of statusupdate model

Comment: For first comment the answer given will work there also. For second comment yeah you can inherit the model but if you want auto update then you have to override the save method or you have to make a custom model maanger. Overriding save method will be more easy.

Comment: Filter from the odometer id then order by date if you have one then select the second index. Just simple orm

Comment: Even if you keep the odometer field solution can be applied. You can still update the field like mentioned above